# GET works in Postman, but not in python. Python cannot read full data, only metadata returned

Tags: rest, postman, epicorerp

I am trying to run queries in our ERP system to collect large sums of data. I can access our Epicor queries via REST API V2. I'm troubleshooting in Postman with the goal of having Python automate the data collection.

My header in Postman contains my basic HTTPS authentication and API key. I'm using the suffix /Data to show the data from this specific query.
[API call in postman using basic HTTPs authentication (username/pass) and API key in the header.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg6Kb.png)

However, in python I can't figure out how to extract the same data. I've tried the API HTTPS address with /?api-key=" "/Data?, but it only returns the metadata of the query. I believe this is a syntax issue within python that I'm missing because it clearly works in postman.

How to I correctly call this API in python to extract the full data and not just the metadata? [Image of metadata returned by Python (removed "/Data?" from query)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCu4b.png)

Note that no combination of suffix (i.e. /Data?, &metadata#data) works in Python. It only returns the metadata, and nothing else.

Comment: You haven't shown us any code at all.  Note that `X-api-key` is an HTTP header; it's not sent as part of the URL or the form data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.